# Is this quotient space Fréchet or Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

I am starting to learn about quotient spaces, but I am facing some troubles.

One of the problems that I'm stuck at is this:

Let $X = \mathbb{R} \times \{ 1, -1 \}$ and let's define the following equivalence relation: $(x,t) \sim (y,s) \iff (x,t) = (y,s) $ or $x=y \neq 0$. Determine whether the quotient space $X / \sim$ is Fréchet and if it is Hausdorff.

The solution only states that it is Fréchet, but not Hausdorff. I have absolutely no idea how to prove it though. The only way of showing that it is Fréchet or Hausdorff I know is by looking at it's neighborhoods, but I'm completely lost, because I'm not accustomed to quotient spaces. I would appreciate a solution and also how can I look at a quotient space (in this example or in general) and intuitively decide if it is Fréchet or Hausdorff.

Comment: A bit confused about your definition of what Frechet means. Does it mean complete metric topology? Then, something Frechet is automatically Hausdorf.

Comment: @Keith to me Frechet meant that for any two points you can find an open neighbourhood of the first point which does not include the second one and similarly an open neighbourhood of the second point which does not contain the first one.

Comment: I see. No relation to the notion I am familiar with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V$ is a neighborhood of $(0,1)$ and $W$ is a neighborhood of $(0,-1)$ in $X/\sim$, then $V\cap W\ne\emptyset$, since $V$ contains a set of the form $(-\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_1)\times\{1\}$ and $W$ contains a set of the form $(-\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_1)\times\{-1\}$. But, if $0<\varepsilon<\min\{\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2\}$, $(\varepsilon,1)=(\varepsilon,-1)\in V\cap W$. Therefore, $X/\sim$ is not Hausdorff.

Can you now see why it is a Fréchet space?

Comment: Thank you, I see it now.